# How to change hyphenation codes with the change of \language in LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, hyphenation

For a word to be "hyphenatable", all its characters must have `\lccode`>0. With `\savinghyphcodes=1` in e-TeX all characters are associated with hyphenation codes by means of a special table (this is the idea behind this e-TeX extension):

```
A = 97
a = 97
B = 98
b = 98
...
```

This special table is initialized based on the values of `` \lccode`\X ``. So, `` \lccode`\X=Y `` is used to set the mapping between character codes and their hyphenation codes in this table. (In LuaTeX this mechanism is no longer used. What mechanism is used in LuaTeX to set this mapping, instead of `` \lccode`\X=Y ``?)

With `\savinghyphcodes=1` during hyphenation this table (*not* `` \lccode`\X ``) is used to find correspondence between character code and its hyphenation code.

Now let us get to the actual question. The problem is caused by the fact, that in LuaTeX `\savinghyphcodes` was suppressed.

In different languages, one and the same character may and may not be used in hyphenation. For example: in English, quote (`'`) can not be part of word, whereas in French it is part of word.

Normally, one has to do `` \lccode`\'=`\' `` and `` \lccode`\'=0 `` manually each time when changing language. By using `\savinghyphcodes=1` this is done automatically.

By compiling the following examples, we show that the word *is* hyphenated in the second case, in spite of the fact that `` \lccode`\' `` is zero. This is because `\savinghyphcodes=1` is used in the format.

```
$ cat `kpsewhich hyph-fr.tex` | iconv -f utf8 -t cp1252 > hyphfr.tex
```

Create myfmt.ini:

```
\input plain
\newlanguage\french
\language\french
\begingroup
\savinghyphcodes=1
\lccode`\'=`\'
\newcount\n \n=128
\loop\ifnum\n<255
\lccode\n=\n
\advance\n by1\repeat
\input hyphfr
\endgroup
\chardef\english=0
\language\english
\dump
```

Generate new format:

```
$ etex -ini -etex myfmt.ini
```

Create test-en.tex:

```
\language\english
\noindent\hsize=1pt
\the\lccode`\'\ l'installation
\bye
```

Compile test-en.tex with new format:

```
$ etex -fmt myfmt test-en.tex
```

Show the output:

```
$ xdvi test-en.dvi
```

Create test-fr.tex:

```
\language\french
\noindent\hsize=1pt
\the\lccode`\'\ l'installation
\bye
```

Compile test-fr.tex with new format:

```
$ etex -fmt myfmt test-fr.tex
```

Show the output:

```
$ xdvi test-fr.dvi
```

How to achieve with LuaTeX the same functionality as was demonstrated with e-TeX?

Comment: I don't know:-) Might be worth asking on luatex list..

Comment: Note you could simplify your examples not to involve making a format, you can use `\hyphenation` in the main document, and in luatex you can use `\patterns` as well.

Comment: As far as I know, no format uses `\savinghyphcodes`.

Comment: @egreg: it is used in `csplain.ini` (via `hyphen.lan`)

Comment: Have you tried with LuaTeX v0.87? There's been a change in this release and according to the  docs  it now does respect `\savinghyphcodes` (and adds `\hjcode` as a way to circumvent this when required).

Comment: @JosephWright: I will report when LuaTeX v0.87 will be packaged with Debian testing.